# How to write a mixed datatype datatable into an EXCEL using OLEDB in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, oledb, export-to-excel, oledbcommand

I have a datatable(obtained from a sql query) with columns of mixed data types that needs to be written into an excel without changing the datatype, here is the code that I have written I took a sample datatable for reference:

```
    DataTable dtA = new DataTable();

    dtA.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));

    dtA.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(decimal));

    dtA.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(DateTime));

    dtA.Columns.Add("col4");

    dtA.Rows.Add("VALUE1", 23.3, "12-06-2021", "VALUE4");

    // Now I am trying to push this datatable into an excel with the same multiple datatypes format:

   OleDbConnection objConn;

   OleDbCommand objCmd;

   OleDbDataAdapter objDatAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter();

   string excelConnectString;

   string reportspath =@"C:\Users\Report.xlsx";

   excelConnectString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1""").Replace("{0}", reportspath);

   objConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectString);

                try

                {

                    objConn.Open();
                    using (objCmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        objCmd.Connection = objConn;

                        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> columnNamesFordtitems = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dtA.Columns)
                        {
                            columnNamesFordtitems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(dataColumn.ColumnName, dataColumn.DataType.ToString()));
                        }

                        string table = "test";
                        
                        DataTable dtSheets = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        bool existsTable = dtSheets.Select().ToList().Exists(sheet => sheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() == table);
                        if (existsTable)
                        {
                            objCmd.CommandText = $"DROP TABLE [{table}];";
                            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }


         //this is the original query in case of common datatype

// objCmd.CommandText = $"CREATE TABLE [{table}] ({String.Join(",", columnNamesFor11A.Select(c => $"[{c}] string").ToArray())});";


   //how to do it in case of multiple datatype

   objCmd.CommandText = $"CREATE TABLE [{table}] ({String.Join(",", columnNamesFordtitems.Select(c => $"[{c.Key, (c.Value)}]").ToArray())});";

   objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        foreach (DataRow row in dtA.Rows)

                        {

                            List<String> rowValues = new List<string>();

                            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)

                            {

                                rowValues.Add((row[column] != null && row[column] != DBNull.Value) ? row[column].ToString() : String.Empty);

                            }

                            objCmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO [{table}]({String.Join(",", columnNamesFordt.Select(c => $"[{c}]"))}) VALUES ({String.Join(",", rowValues.Select(r => $"'{r}'").ToArray())});";


                            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }
```

Any suggestions or solution would be really helpful for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't help but think that EPPlus would make your life easier here

Comment: Haven't got VS here to test this but I'm pretty sure that you must specify HDR=YES as otherwise what would the columns be called.